# Linkedin API to get ALL company's profiles

Tags: linkedin-api

can anyone please confirm that is it possible to get ALL companies LinkedIn profiles through LinkedIn API ? i have searched a lot about it but could not get any related result.

Answer (score 1):

It requires that you have a partnership-level relationship with LinkedIn to be granted the required permissions to get that data. You can apply to be a member of the partner program on the [LinkedIn Developer Network](http://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs/apply).

Comment: @user1438038...........so will it be possible if we have partnership with linkedin ?

Comment: Have you checked the reference I gave? When in doubt, contact LinkedIn support. They will know for sure.